# Performance of Tensorflow distributed training is much slower than caffe multi-GPU training

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained inceptionv3 using tensorflow both on multi-GPU version and distributed version (two machine, four GPU each). Each GPU processes 32 images per iteration under both settings. However, the distributed training speed is twice as slow as the `caffe` multi-GPU version. I'm wondering how to improve the performance of distributed training.

**Configuration:**

Two machine, both of them have totally same environment: CentOS 7, 4 GTX TITAN X GPUs, 32 Intel Xeon CPU E5-2630 v3 2.40GHz processors, and 131GB Memory. Network IO between machines is 125MB/s, `ping` delay is 0.1ms and local read speed is 1GB/s (RAID5). The distributed training code is the newest master branch [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception). In distributed version, there are 4 `workers` on each machine, each work are assigned to 1 GPU and there is only one `ps` server started. I read data file from local disk.

the start script for each worker (8 workers in total) is

```
~/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=32 \
--data_dir=/data1/imagenet1k \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=2 \
--ps_hosts='10.10.102.28:2220' \
--worker_hosts='10.10.102.28:2221,10.10.102.28:2222,10.10.102.28:2223,10.10.102.28:2224,10.10.102.29:2221,10.10.102.29:2222,10.10.102.29:2223,10.10.102.29:2224' &
```

**Runtime logging:**

The training speed is

```
INFO:tensorflow:Worker 6: 2016-05-16 21:07:22.101672: step 390, loss = 8.15(24.0 examples/sec; 1.334  sec/batch)
INFO:tensorflow:Worker 5: 2016-05-16 21:07:22.101666: step 390, loss = 8.10(24.0 examples/sec; 1.335  sec/batch)
INFO:tensorflow:Worker 4: 2016-05-16 21:07:22.101768: step 390, loss = 8.11(24.0 examples/sec; 1.333  sec/batch)
INFO:tensorflow:Worker 7: 2016-05-16 21:07:22.102245: step 390, loss = 8.03(24.1 examples/sec; 1.330  sec/batch)
```

This speed is twice as slow as `caffe` multi-GPU training on one machine(ensure that experiments are under same settings, each GPU process 32 images per iteration). I used `nvidia-smi -l 1` to watch the GPU usage, and find that GPUs only busy in 25% running time. The `top` command print like this:

```
 %Cpu(s):  2.4 us, 35.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 62.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13174038+total, 21064972 free, 18241616 used, 92433792 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16724332 free,    52880 used. 88948128 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
  685 peter+  20   0  0.191t 2.336g 453624 S 878.1  1.9  83:03.03 python      
15102 peter+  20   0 13.715g 5.522g  41820 S 293.7  4.4 348:39.74 python      
  682 peter+  20   0  0.192t 2.476g 453608 S  13.0  2.0  69:18.00 python      
  683 peter+  20   0  0.193t 4.093g 978228 S  11.6  3.3  84:40.56 python      
  684 peter+  20   0  0.191t 2.410g 453612 S  10.6  1.9  88:50.77 python
```

**What I have tried**

- By modifying the `num_preprocess_threads` and the `num_readers`, I got the best performance `1.333  sec/batch`, when I set both variable to 1.
- Modify the queue capacity is not helpful.
- I believe the `bath_inputs()` is executed on `CPU:0`, because in `image_processing.py` line 132: `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):`
- I refered to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/47) and wondering if the bottleneck is CPU/IO.

How to get a better performance ?

Comment: Hard to tell. What are you computing? what is your bandwidth and transfer speed between the computers ? How did you segment the program on your node ?

Comment: Thanks, I added more device information on it.